# Filter AD Groups By Organizational Unit

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to create a power shell script that prompts input for specific AD groups that a particular org manages that will essentially filter out users that are no longer in the said org and ONLY returns the 'samaccountname' and current department for those particular users. I have started but it does not seem to filter correctly. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
$groupName = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Please enter AD group name to display users no longer in department:", "XYZ", "$env")
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupName -Recursive | Get-ADUser -Properties Department -Filter {enabled -eq $true} | ? {$_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*,OU=XYZ,*"} | Select-Object SamAccountName,Department
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears it doesn't like the -Filter you have for Get-ADUser, I think (not 100% on this) it is because coming through the pipeline, it is sending one user at a time, so there isn't anything to filter.

Here's what I would do/try (maybe a better way, but testing this seems to get where you want to go):

```
$MatchedUsers=@{}
$GroupMembers=Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupName -Recursive | Get-ADUser -Properties Department

ForEach ($User in $GroupMembers) {
    If (($User.Enabled -eq "True") -and ($User.DistinguishedName -notlike "*,OU=XYZ,*")) {
        $MatchedUsers=@{
            'SamAccountName'=$User.SamAccountName
            'Department'=$User.Department
        }
    $obj=New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $MatchedUsers
    Write-Output $obj
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I guess I'm not filtering at a high enough level of the OU so it's still bringing back all the users in the group. Any idea on how to identify the top level of the distinguished name?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure I totally understand.  Are you looking to remove users from a particular AD Group that are no longer at the organization?

Comment: Exactly. Well I won't have the required access via this particular admin account to remove the users via powershell  but I do want to identify those users.

Comment: I guess that depends on how the organization removes them.  If they delete the account in Active Directory entirely, then they'll be removed automatically.  Otherwise if the account is Disabled in AD, then in the above code, $User.Enabled -eq "False" would search for users in AD who have their account Disabled.